# problem with filter data using ajax in laravel 8

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-8

I want to filter the data in my table. I want if I select the first box it will show the data accordingly and if I select the second box it will show the data accordingly but the problem is that if I select the first box here the data does not show then the second box has to be selected.

Here is my controller code

```
public function UpazilaWiseReportShow(Request $request){ 

       $data = [];
       $data['report_data'] = Report::distric()->status(1)     
       ->where('upazila_id',$request->upazila_id)->where('fiscal_year', $request->fiscal_year)
       ->get();
        return view('adc.reports.upazilla-wise-data', $data);
    }
```

here is my view code

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#upazila_id').on('change', function() {
          getFilterData();
        });
        $('#fiscal_year').on('change', function (e) {
                    getFilterData();
        });
    });
    function getFilterData() {
 
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: {
         upazila_id: $("[name=upazila_id]").val(),
         fiscal_year: $("[name=fiscal_year]").val()
        },
        url: "{{url('adc/upazila-wise-report')}}",
        success:function(data) {
          $("#report_data_table").html(data);
        }
      });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: In first case you do not have fiscal_year so you need some if check to run it properly

Comment: Yes its run properly, when I select both box the data show but when I select one of the box data not showen

Answer (score 0):

You should check if your $request has your needed fields. So you have to check if your request has these fields. You can use **when** method for it.

With the code below, you can either select fiscal year or upazila_id or both.

```
    $data['report_data'] = Report::distric()
        ->status(1)
        ->when(
            isset($request->upazila_id),
            function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('upazila_id', $request->upazila_id);
            }
        )
        ->when(
            isset($request->fiscal_year),
            function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('fiscal_year', $request->fiscal_year);
            }
        )
        ->get();
```

Comment: I think its may be my select menu option default value problem can you check my ajax code? Please tell me how Can I prevent default?

Comment: Do you have FormRequest validation? dd($request->upazila_id); what is returning? or fiscal_year? And how is your view/HTML code

Comment: Everything is working fine but I need to select two boxes to show data. I add my select option in code please see

Comment: Please tell me how can I prevent Choose menu option from query?

Comment: Please add your view code your question so everyone can see it.